# ssh not working: Connection closed by remote host

Tags: ssh, git

I was using ssh key but one day suddenly it stopped working. This is what I get when I try to clone. Also, there is nothing in the known_hosts file. What do I do?

```
sarthak@Sarthak:~/.ssh$ git clone git@github.com:sarthmit/Andrew-Ng-ML-solutions.git
Cloning into 'Andrew-Ng-ML-solutions'...
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

sarthak@Sarthak:~/Desktop/Web Scraping$ ssh -vvv git@github.com
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "github.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.253.113] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/sarthak/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/sarthak/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/sarthak/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/sarthak/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/sarthak/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/sarthak/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/sarthak/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/sarthak/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: 

debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: 

debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: Error:  Must authenticate before using this service.


ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Comment: `ssh -vvv git@github.com`.

Comment: Post edited to show the result of ssh -vvv git@github.com

Comment: A similar question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10127818/ssh-exchange-identification-connection-closed-by-remote-host-under-git-bash

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.253.113] port 22.
```

That does not look like github IP

```
debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: Error:  Must authenticate before using this service.
```

That is not SSH identification string.

You are connecting from behind some proxy/firewall that prevents you from using SSH. You should talk with your network administrator.

Or use HTTPS to clone your github repositories.

Answer (score 0):

I got exactly the same issue.

192.30.253.113 IS a github IP without any problem.

For my case, I have "service filter" rule in my router setting, which disabled port 22 for some reason.

You can try to check your router configurations as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this problem - Gitlab server was actually down for planned maintenance!

ie: nothing wrong on my client end.